# React JS Application Freezes during onChanged for input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My ReactJs Application has been freezing whenever I type into an input field. It was initially working smoothly, but then this issue occurred yesterday. I have changed onChange to on submit, but that also does not help. I could type one character, and the application will freeze. I deleted the built pages, like profile update, profile delete, profile verification, admin update, and admin delete, which require the user to type into an input field and leave the login page. However, that also does not help. I will provide the code via CodeSandbox. Any help is appreciated!

https://codesandbox.io/s/bible-trivia-rebuild-czfhgs

Comment: What have you changed from it working smoothly to today?

Comment: The last know page that I created when I knew it was working was the admin verification page. Let me upload that code. Please standby!

Comment: Added the admin verification page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `<Header />`. You put an async call `GetAdminRole()` in component top-level. Then you chain it to a `setState` call, which effectively make it an async loop (async-call -> setState -> re-render -> async-call -> ...)
.

Once identify the problem, it's an easy fix:

```
// GetAdminRole(userLoggedIn, loggedInUser).then((res) => setAdminLevel(res));
  useEffect(() => {
    GetAdminRole(userLoggedIn, loggedInUser).then((res) => setAdminLevel(res));
  }, [userLoggedIn, loggedInUser])
```

Moral of the story: never trigger `setState` from a render function.

Comment: Totally understand, thank you for the explanation!